# Spring Boot 2.5 Loading Schema.sql Invalid SQL statement

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

[image]

Before `spring boot 2.5` release everything is working fine, but after spring boot 2.5 I am having problems while creating tables from `schema.sql`

> rg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating
> bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class
> path resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]:
> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException:
> Failed to execute SQL script statement #2 of URL
> [jar:file:/opt/chetankrishna/myproject/lib/some-project-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/schema.sql]:
> new_next_idx number; nested exception is
> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

Comment: Please copy&paste your code instead of making a screen shot, that makes it easier to try it out and help you. Also, please use the formatting possibilities for your log messages.